# password hashing in freeswitch for ldap authentication

Tags: authentication, openldap, freeswitch

My freeswitch authenticate with opnldap server successfully.but when i select userPassword for user extension authentication it fails.

From my experiments and test i found that freeswitch sending password in plain text.

Test 1: 
when i set ldap password in md5 , in freeswitch cli i see hash password fetched from ldap server and authentication failed.

Test 2: 
when i set ldap password in plain text, in freeswitch cli i can see plain text password fetched from ldap server and authentication success.

how to hash password in freeswitch for Ldap authentication.?

Comment: Passwords are not encrypted in LDAP: they are hashed.

Comment: i want to hash password in freeswitch . How to do it .. ?